# TailwindCSS angled border

Tags: tailwind-css

I have managed to create a border which is cut at an angle in the following way ->

https://play.tailwindcss.com/b9oILu69my

Basically, I have a big container, inside of it I have a smaller container where I'm placing the border and setting the color of the bottom/right borders to transparent, in this way achieving what I am looking for.

Now I am trying to do the same thing, however, I want the border to be placed on the bottom-right side instead of the top-left

I've tried hundreds of variations of the code shown in the playground, but to no avail.

To be even more precise in what exactly I am trying to achieve ->

[Detailed example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv5Hy.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a somewhat different approach, by using an `absolute` positioned rotated `div`, within a `div` with `overflow-hidden`. If you keep the main image (the yellow square) centered with `m-auto`, the border will be the same size on both sides. On the yellow div you need to set a z-index that is higher then the rotated div.

```
<div class="flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-50 py-6 sm:py-12">
  <div class="relative flex m-auto h-40 w-40 overflow-hidden rounded-lg">
    <div class="absolute top-8 left-8 m-auto h-96 w-96 bg-blue-200 rotate-45"></div>
      <div class="top-3 z-30 right-3 m-auto rounded-lg h-32 w-32 bg-yellow-300"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[You can find my Tailwind playground example here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/szyUNv4KZh)

You can play with the height and width of the div’s using [arbitrary values](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support), like `w-[48rem]` and `rotate-[60deg]`.

Edit: [this example looks more like yours](https://play.tailwindcss.com/U1c6mqM8C2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I was attempting to do it via borders, but as you pointed this is a much simpler solution! Thank you =)

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Good luck!